# From nested list extract object from particular position in R

Tags: r

I create the following nested list in R

```
M= list()
K=3
iter = 2
for(k in 1:K){
  M[[k]] = list()
  for(i in 1:K){
    M[[k]][[i]] = array(0,c(K+1,K+1,iter))
  }
}
```

The values of `K` and `iter` can vary. My goal is for a particular list `M[[k]]` to extract the matrices corresponding iter value from all the lists inside the `M[[k]]` list. The nested list M is of the form

```
M
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0    0

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0    0


[[1]][[2]]
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0    0

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0    0


[[1]][[3]]
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0    0

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0    0



[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0    0

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0    0


[[2]][[2]]
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0    0

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0    0


[[2]][[3]]
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0    0

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0    0



[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0    0

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0    0


[[3]][[2]]
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0    0

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0    0


[[3]][[3]]
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0    0

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0    0
```

Based on that I would like to write generic command where for any value of `k` and `iter` I'll take the corresponding layer of matrices. For example, for `k=2` and `iter=2` I would like to take back the following list

```
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0    0

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0    0

[[3]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0    0
```

which this result is `list(M[[k]][[1]][,,iter]],M[[k]][[2]][,,iter]],M[[k]][[3]][,,iter]])`. But I want to generalize that result in an automatic way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function using `lapply()`:

```
get_iters <- function(M, k, iter) lapply(M[[k]], \(x) x[,,iter])

get_iters(M, k = 2, iter = 2)
```

Comment: I try to use the code ```get_iters <- function(M, k, iter) lapply(M[[k]], \(x) x[,,iter])
``` but I get the following erro ```Error: unexpected input in "get_iters <- function(M, k, iter) lapply(M[[k]], \"```

Comment: @Jonathan1234 what version of R are you using? If < 4.1, you can instead use `get_iters <- function(M, k, iter) lapply(M[[k]], function(x) x[,,iter])`, or upgrade. `\(x)` is a shorthand anonymous function syntax that was introduced with R 4.1